# C# working with access errors

Tags: c#

I am not sure why but in c# the DLG is an error as well as dao. can some one help me resolve these issues ?

Error   1   The type or namespace name 'dao' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   c:\users\dhelm.allmatinc.001\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\allianceerp\allianceerp\form1.cs 1074    13  AllianceERP

```
           app.OpenCurrentDatabase(dlg.FileName, false, "");

           dao.Database db = app.CurrentDb();
           dao.Recordset rs = db.OpenRecordset(sql, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

how do i properly use this

Comment: What is the actual error you're getting? What is the DLG? You need to provide more context for this question to be answered

Comment: sorry if i add more code stack over flow freaks and wont let me post

Comment: Error 3 The type or namespace name 'dao' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\users\dhelm.allmatinc.001\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\allianceerp\allianceerp\form1.cs 1066 13 AllianceERP

Comment: and for further reference http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22195/Print-Microsoft-Access-Reports-from-C

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what's wrong. Are you referencing the correct dll? Do you have the proper using statement in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample that you are using from code project is missing an import. The DAO library should be referenced, it can be [downloaded from here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5793). It should be noted that this is a deprecated library. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but this library is probably not the best way to go about solving this anymore (the article is from 2007).